# Rails: request.remote_id returns six-digit number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ip, ip-address

I'm trying to build a voting function that won't let one user vote twice, but I don't want to make anyone login, so instead I want to record a user's IP address and ban it. I did the following:

View:

```
<%= link_to "vote", vote_user_path(@user), method: :post, :class => "btn" %>
```

Controller:

```
def vote
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  Vote.create!(ip: request.remote_ip, voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: "User")
  redirect_to @user
end
```

But for some reason Vote.last.ip returns "127.0.0.1". I mean, I don't know much about IP addresses, but there's no way it's supposed to be a six-digit number, right? Am I doing something wrong, or is it different for some reason because I'm in development mode?

Comment: You are not restricting users to login for voting? If not then why there's `user.find(params[:id])` in controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is not a six digit number, it's the IP address of localhost.

If you're running the rails application server on the same machine where you're testing this, then that's the reason you're getting `127.0.0.1`.  If you tested your application from a different machine from within a reachable network then you should see accurate IP.

See documentation on [`remote_ip`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Request/remote_ip)for details.

As far as your restricting by IP design is concerned, if users are behind a [`NAT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) then you'll be banning not just one single user.  I'm sure you must have thought about this before coming up with the design.

Comment: How common is that? Not every wifi network is its own ip address right?

Comment: It's common for an Internet Service Provider (ISP) to assign only one IP address per residential customer, and that one address is usually assigned to a household modem or router. From the outside, every device connected to that router (wifi or not) will have the same IP address. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-are-ip-addresses-in-home-networking.html

Answer (score 1):

[IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) addresses they are most often written in the dot-decimal notation, which consists of four octets of the address expressed individually in decimal and separated by periods eg:`250.199.354.123`.

On most computer systems, [`localhost`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) resolves to the address `127.0.0.1` , which is the most-commonly used `IPv4` loopback address.

`remote_ip` determines originating IP address which is localhost in your case. And as previously mentioned, it  resolves to the address `127.0.0.1`.

`request.remote_ip` returns the string `"127.0.0.1"` if you vote from the device that is running the server.

You should know it's easy to get other IPs to spoof, or lose the votes of numerous valid users on the same network (having the same IP address).

Comment: And I'm assuming the best way to do that would simply be `request.remote_id.to_s` ?

Comment: @vee I personally prefer you answer, I'm gonna upvote it and enhance mine. Thanks for your comment.